# changing style of a select HTML option

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to style the option of a html “select”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

I have an HTML  element and I want one of the options to be in italic. I don't remember where but I've seen select elements that have a combination of bold fonts and regular fonts; may be it was a custom-built control.

Here's the HTML:

```
<select>
   <option>select a timezone</option>
   <option value="0">Casablanca</option>
   <option value="0">Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London</option>
   <option value="60">Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague</option>
   <option value="60" style="font-style:italic;">Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
</select>​
```

And here is the [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/E7r8w/1/)

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: you're going to find options to style options very limited as IE and Safari have issues applying the full CSS spectrum to an option: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/11/bug-291-no-styling-options-in-ie.html and in particular italic won't work in IE, Safari, or Chrome :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/) is a great reference on how to use font-style on an option tag.  It seems that you can't do it in certain browsers, and there are certain limitations.

Answer (score 1):

```
option:nth-child(3){
 font-style:italic
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E7r8w/2/

alternatively you can use javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/E7r8w/3/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Chrome, or IE.  Does it work for you?

Comment: @ajon I didn't test in Chrome or IE... just firefox.  i think the nth-child() selector is css3.